# LoRa and LoRaWAN

Tags: server, communication, gateway, lora, lorawan

I am trying understand LoRA and LoRaWAN technologies.
I want to establish comunication between my end nodes and gateway and I want gateways communicate own non-LoRaWAN server.
What shold be rules? For exmaple; Must uplink/donwnlink count per day, duty cycle etc. comply with ETSI EU863-870 or LoRaWAN-allinace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically after a device has joined a network it has liberty to send or receive telegrams at its own time frames. The receive windows of the end nodes differ depending on the class type.

With respect to rules:

1. All end nodes should adhere to 1% duty cycle.
2. The regional specifications can give you more insights into the rules. You can find the information here - https://lora-alliance.org/resource_hub/rp2-101-lorawan-regional-parameters-2/

Comment: Note: Duty cycle is more stringent after 1 hour and 24 hours in case of repeated transmission such as join attempts for LoRaWAN v1.0.4+